# How to determine if an app is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: android

Since Google published a new requirement for Android Apps, where Apps that have 32 bit architecture can be published on Google Play Store until August 2021 I am looking for a method how to determine if my App, that is available on Google Play Store, will fit these new requirements?

The source is the following site: https://9to5google.com/2019/01/15/android-app-64-bit-requirement/

I read a question before and the answer was that one does not need to worry if there is only Java Code and  no NDK Code. But one needs to update the used libraries to 64 bit.

That was a bit unclear for me. So what should we do as developers to apply on Google's new timeline for Android Apps? How can we see in Android Studio if we are using 32 bit or 64 bit ? And how to maintain the used libraries?

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: @MuratKaragöz thank you very much.